# Restore point via C# trouble

Tags: c#, .net, restore-points

My task is to find all old restore points(not only system restore points,custom app restore points also included) and delete them. Also I must know their total size, and their description.
I have two solutions:
1) Find and delete at "C:\System Volume Information" redundant file.In this case I don't have any description of this restore point for showing it to the user.
2) Use System.Management.ManagementClass for getting info about restore points.

```
var sysRestore = new ManagementClass("\\\\.\\root\\default", "systemrestore", new ObjectGetOptions());
```

But in this case I don't have total restore points size.Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't provide the size of course.  Good thing that you only care about "old restore points", it certainly gives you the CreationTime.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How to find all old restore points with file size and point description properties? Also methods to delete them?